# Why does RecordRTC always set my mime type to x-matroska

Tags: recordrtc

Im trying to record a video from my webcam with the node package 'recordrtc' (im using angular).

Even though i set the mime type in the options to 'video/webm' it always seems to switch it back to 'x-matroska'...

Here is my code:

```
[...]

this.options = { 
    mimeType: 'video/webm',
    bitsPerSecond: 51200000,
    frameRate: 60
}

// After getting the Video Devices
this.recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream, this.options);

[...]

startRecording() {
    this.recordRTC.startRecording();
}

stopRecording() {
    this.recordRTC.stopRecording(this.processVideo.bind(this));
}

processVideo(videoWebMural) {
    console.log(this.recordRTC.getBlob());
    this.recordRTC.getDataURL((url) => {
        console.log(url);
    })
}
```

For some reason when i console log this blob, it says

```
> Blob {size: 149322, type: 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1'}
```

And when i log the base64 string of the video with 'this.recordRTC.getDataURL' it aswell starts with:

```
> data:video/x-matroska [...]
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1070856